# Estilização de HR

Tags: css

Tenho uma linha em um layout que estou fazendo, e não queria criar uma `div` só pra ela.
Gostaria de continuar a hierarquia que criei. Então decidi usar o `<hr />`
Exemplo:

```
.empresa hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

O que acontece, é que, olhando com zoom, tenho a impressão de que a altura da linha não fica em **1px**, tenho a impressão de que já uma borda.

Isso é normal? O `<hr />` ainda é usual?

Comment: Eu geralmente uso border mesmo, pra evitar essa complicação. HR é chato de estilizar. Lembrando que em alguns casos, mesmo pra estilizar o HR você tem a cor E a borda, em outros casos o HR pode ser "só borda". E ainda tem que ajustar padding e margem, pra ficar igual nos browsers. Se não alterar a semântica da página, acho melhor usar SPAN ou DIV estilizados.

Comment: ai que tá, tenho uma div acima desse `hr` que é só texto, vai ficar estranho eu colocar borda.

Comment: Não ponha borda no texto, ponha um `<span class="regua"></span>` no lugar do HR, e no CSS defina algo do tipo: `.regua {display:block; padding:0; margin: 10px 0; width:100%; height:1px; background-color:#ddd}`. Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/6t6jz732/**

Comment: PS: eu tambem preferiria usar `<hr>` em vez desse tipo de coisa, mas tem hora que não compensa. A pergunta é bem relevante, de qq forma, e espero que o pessoal ponha soluções bem completas e bem testadas em varios _browsers_.

Answer (score 1):

A `hr` também possui bordas. Tente fazer o seguinte, eliminar as boras laterais e a borda inferior, por exemplo.

```
.empresa hr {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0px;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```